# Corrupted rasters after import into ArcGIS FGDB

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster

I have been seeing a number of corrupted rasters recently after importing them into file geodatabases (FGDB).  The image below left shows a .tif prior to the import, while the image to the right shows the image after importing into the FGDB.  Could these errors be due to NoData handling?  What could be causing these errors?

**Source TIFF info:**

- Columns and Rows: 5985, 7571
- Bands: 1
- Cellsize: 1,1 m
- uncompressed Size: 21.61 MB
- Source Type: continuous
- Pixel Type: Unsigned integer
- Pixel Depth: 4 Bit
- Number of classes: 4
- Storage Location: Google Drive

[image]

Comment: What compression method did you have set in the environments when you copied the files?  Have you zoomed all the way in (in ArcMap) on the problem areas to see if the error is present in the pyramids, or just the base data?